# The emulator process for avd has terminated(Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI4Ny.jpg)

The emulator process for avd has terminated(Android Studio)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main root cause of that issue is lack of free space on your disk

Comment: I have 300 gb of free space

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same issue when I shut down the emulator while the process is still running in command line. It is caused by the multi instance lock. You can try the following:

1. Open AVD manager and find the emulator you are using, open the drop down options and click "open on disk", it will open `...\Pixel_X_API_xx.avd`
2. Delete the file called `multiinstance.lock`, you may be asked to kill a process which names like qemuXXX, do that in your Task Manager.
3. Reopen the emulator, if still not working, delete any file related to "lock" in the folder.
4. If still not working, uninstall the emulator and install it again.

This is one of the most ANNOYING issues of Android Studio. I cannot understand why they haven't solved it so far.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator tends to leave zombie processes lying around when it is terminated, particularly if the device it was running wasn't powered down by pressing the power button.

Look for processes with qemu or emulator in their names and kill them. You may need kill -9 on Linux. This will delete the lock files and enable the emulator to restart.

Also look at the answers to

[Why does latest Android Studio emulator crash or get stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336224/why-does-latest-android-studio-emulator-crash-or-get-stuck)