# Emulator process terminated, how do I get Android Studio emulators to run?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, sdk, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

How do I get Android Studio virtual devices to run (stop terminating)?
Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1)

This is the first time using Android Studio for me and I'm trying to get the Android emulator to work, to start learning Java. Everytime I try to run an emulator I get the following message:

`The emulator process for AVD {device-name} has terminated.`

[image]

I feel like I've tried everything I could find on the web. Here's what I have tried so far:

- **Checking my disk space** as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70364427/17225961) and even removing some unnecessary applications, despite having more than enough disk space (well over 80 GB).
- **Removing every virtual device** and re-installing them again one by one using the built in Device Manager.
- **Removing the Android Emulator** entirely and re-installing it from within the SDK Tools tab, found under the Tools > SDK Manager application menu.
- **Creating an advancedFeatures.ini file** under C:\Users\ {name}\ .android\ as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70262394/17225961) and in other posts with different lines in the file.
- **Restarting my PC and Android Studio** throughout the entire process, after every step mentioned here.
- **Removing Android Studio** completely from my system, then downloading it (from the official website) and installing it again.
- **Looking at the idea.log file**. There's a bunch of errors regarding the emulator, which I cannot make sense of.

Does anybody have an idea what to do?

**Here's what the idea.log file says about the emulator:**

```
2022-05-16 10:23:53,804 [ 308433]   WARN - alytics.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80' 
2022-05-16 10:24:46,048 [ 360677]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_5_API_Tiramisu -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-05-16 10:24:47,098 [ 361727]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_5_API_Tiramisu -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-05-16 10:24:49,548 [ 364177]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. 
2022-05-16 10:24:49,564 [ 364193]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release. 
2022-05-16 10:24:49,564 [ 364193]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only. 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,046 [ 365675]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,046 [ 365675]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,073 [ 365702]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,073 [ 365702]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Sending adb public key [QAAAAC03lzdbz2r7trf4HeurXGQ9LdN2Kex6Luf2QjY0wlgNvxm+NCxU0TyJXB+NOfqXcglhbuChvc1zyLz57tbnSrH5zzmXMzN4WmbS9BTW5uIuNfLGP+TQRdHvBiWvqgkOSOKqp4NQiclDOfet4EuGUqRvxGuKbEYLWMsVHfMnXWSOuuUr5hQl1s/MPKkthtC0fVTDJMQIV5xAN85Z9pUhUqOdxPyU4X8xvo/nFFOaZLD4h+UyKp4Yn6WXvm+Q0aceAr2YvEirpBUbj2KFoMzFP29kokuZTmtENhEF/WQXjQ8OhecQ99z3NUQdIhWDk3x8xKvkWepxWCtKVGn3jCJObE8c4bGt2OUmsWQkvVP/9/5wh+B0qLTtInXtoQiNman64QEvrZMYOPZxIJ+RNBExu5pJytEK5ntxQhQPUcL3aY+mNNCQotGXyJrxPIvtiEJyUFHfQcM+Ulned9eDGTNN0TcOOWjBcKUoMt9NllZ5/mUCSsf0rgyy4YvtLiqV/1EWxYo96kl+v8MH6jMiJN9MHgzPFZMt8+azTZGDoDIbo7T5aBvv3hvECUCiWwIdbhQmK6bKdNqjd8ovnF0hAcporw0iPC+mNWiC9onVToMgJE7oRwtCi42voElCDTl/+cuEVnBREVjk16I31fuWIewM6pBoSM7F3wwPbjRXbsedpuQ613f+HwEAAQA= @unknown] 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,074 [ 365703]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - added library C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\vulkan\vulkan-1.dll 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,074 [ 365703]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Rootcanal has  been activated. 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,074 [ 365703]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,508 [ 366137]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,510 [ 366139]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local+token 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,511 [ 366140]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Advertising in: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_3028.ini 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,915 [ 366544]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-05-16 10:24:51,915 [ 366544]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Deleting snapshot default_boot 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,061 [ 366690]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Shutting down gRPC endpoint 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,062 [ 366691]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Shutting down gRPC endpoint 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,074 [ 366703]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Closing down rootcanal. 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,473 [ 367102]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Running multiple emulators with the same AVD 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,474 [ 367103]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,485 [ 367114]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,486 [ 367115]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - OS: Windows 10 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,487 [ 367116]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Last Action:  
2022-05-16 10:24:52,487 [ 367116]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - is an experimental feature. 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,487 [ 367116]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,487 [ 367116]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,488 [ 367117]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - OS: Windows 10 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,488 [ 367117]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Last Action:  
2022-05-16 10:24:52,488 [ 367117]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,489 [ 367118]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,489 [ 367118]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,489 [ 367118]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - OS: Windows 10 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,490 [ 367119]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Last Action:  
2022-05-16 10:24:52,491 [ 367120]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A) 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,588 [ 367217]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Process finished with exit code 1 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,588 [ 367217]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Emulator terminated with exit code 1 
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code 1
  at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:182)
  at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:247)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:221)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:54)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:247)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:205)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:280)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:188)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:184)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:99)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
  at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:213)
  at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-05-16 10:24:52,591 [ 367220]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,592 [ 367221]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,592 [ 367221]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - OS: Windows 10 
2022-05-16 10:24:52,593 [ 367222]  ERROR - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Last Action:  
2022-05-16 10:24:53,887 [ 368516]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A) 
2022-05-16 10:24:53,950 [ 368579]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API Tiramisu - Process finished with exit code 0 
2022-05-16 10:24:54,122 [ 368751]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected 
2022-05-16 10:25:38,691 [ 413320]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appClangTidySettings took 16 ms, NotificationConfiguration took 15 ms, YamlEditorOptions took 16 ms 
2022-05-16 10:25:38,769 [ 413398]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=Learning_Environment, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\{username}\AndroidStudioProjects\Learning_Environment)FileEditorManager took 15 ms, ServiceViewManager took 16 ms, Vcs.Log.Tabs.Properties took 16 ms, XDebuggerManager took 15 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know an exact cause of this problem - it seems something related to graphics, and happened after last emulator update in my case.

What helped me was running emulator using console and changing graphics settings. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 so all paths are for linux.

1. List all your avds: `$./emulator -list-avds`
2. Then start avd with software acceleration mode: `$./emulator -avd MY_AVD_NAME -gpu swiftshader_indirect` - this very line started my avd. This is enough to use the emulator.
3. (Optional) I wanted to be able to start emulator from Android Studio, so tried different settings in avd, and what works was: [image: settings for avd]
   After this you can run your avd from AS or just with `$./emulator -avd MY_AVD_NAME`

Also it looks like there is an alternative way: change setting in `/home/user/.android/avd/MY_AVD_NAME.avd/config.ini` file:

```
hw.gpu.enabled = yes
hw.gpu.mode = swiftshader_indirect
```

Google link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#command-gpu

Comment: thank you, only your solution with -gpu swiftshader_indirect helped to open the emulator for me!

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the graphic of your emulator from automatic to Software

[image]

Comment: This option is greyed out for me :(

Comment: try to select emulator having no play store. I was facing similar issue when I select emulator with play store.

Answer (score 2):

/windows 11; Android Studio Flamingo/

In my case the error:
Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515

Was caused from the missing dll: mfplat.dll witch is a part of the Media Feature Pack.

In Android Studio -> Help -> Show log in explorer
In explorer dialog open the file: idea.log

2023-06-08 22:43:07,614 [ 235189]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 API 31 - C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_3_API_31 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-06-08 22:43:07,625 [ 235200]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 API 31 - Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A)
2023-06-08 22:43:07,625 [ 235200]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 API 31 - Found systemPath C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-31\google_apis_playstore\x86_64
2023-06-08 22:43:07,967 [ 235542]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 API 31 - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
2023-06-08 22:43:07,967 [ 235542] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 3 API 31 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
**java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515**
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:184)
...

Above the error, there is a execution command:
**C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_3_API_31 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300**

/copy it from your log file, these paths are in my machine/
I've pasted this command in command promt (cmd) and the error dialog appears with message:
This application failed to start because mfplat.dll was not found...

To install Media Feature Pack in windows 11:
Settings -> Apps -> Optional features
In search field: Media feature pack
and click install, after that restart the computer

Comment: Great job! Works for me!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438813/android-emulator-version-32-1-11-february-8-2023-and-higher-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Do the cold boot of your emulator; no need to reinstall or change any settings. It is possibly the issue when the device doesn't shut down correctly.[image: Cold Boot Now button]