# Android emulator version 32.1.11 (February 8, 2023) and higher does not work

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Android emulator version 32.1.11 (February 8, 2023) and higher does not work, release notes

- Network speed optimizations
- Mouse support in Embedded Emulator
- Virtio-snd improvements
- Disable the usage of symlinks while unzipping the Android Emulator during installation
- Fix crash in emulator-check

Android emulator version 31.3.14 (December 13, 2022) and below works well

Top level (common error) is: The emulator process for AVD Pixel has terminated.

Log with stacktrace:

> 2023-06-09 01:27:45,661 [  10511]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33
>
> - C:\Users\evghe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_33 2023-06-09 01:27:45,676 [  10526]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33
> - Android emulator version 32.1.11.0 (build_id 9536276) (CL:N/A) 2023-06-09 01:27:45,676 [  10526]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33
> - Found systemPath C:\Users\evghe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64
>   2023-06-09 01:27:45,723 [  10573]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33
> - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135) 2023-06-09 01:27:45,723 [  10573] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33 - Emulator
>   terminated with exit code -1073741515 java.lang.Throwable: Emulator
>   terminated with exit code -1073741515     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:184)     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
>   at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy57.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:222)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:54)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
>   at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy57.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:206)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:281)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:189)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:185)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:98)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
>   at
>   com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:212)
>   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
>   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) 2023-06-09
>   01:27:45,723 [  10573] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33 - Android
>   Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2  Build
>   #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639 2023-06-09 01:27:45,723 [  10573] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 2023-06-09 01:27:45,723 [  10573] SEVERE
> - Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 33 - OS: Windows 10

- I have Intel CPU and Windows 10 (tried also 11)
- In bios virtualization is enabled
- In Windows Features - Hyper V is disabled, Virtual Machine Platform is disabled, Windows hypervisor platform is disabled, Windows Sandbox is disabled
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAMX installer) 7.6.5 from Android Studio SDK Tools is installed (also tried manually install latest 7.8.0 version)
- Android Emulator hypervisor driver 2.0.0 from Android Studio SDK Tools isn't installed

Any help, thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: @Junaid - No...

Comment: Answer: I'm using Windows 11 Pro N, which means the Media Feature Pack is not installed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76435812/1006626